# UTC formatted string to UTC Date Object using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, date, utc, android-date

I have a **UTC** formatted DateTime **String**

and need this String to be converted to DATE Object without any Format change.

Currently, when I try to convert it to a date Object it is returned as GMT formatted Date object as depicted in the image attached below.

I have a limitation of using **SimpleDateFormat** as I have to support **API<21** also.

```
String newDateString = "2022-06-27 08:27:00 UTC";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.EnumDateFormats.DATE_FORMAT7);//"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'"
                format.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                Date date = format.parse(newDateString);
                System.out.println(date);//printing GMT formatted Date object but I need Date object in UTC format like 2022-06-27 08:27:00 UTC
```

I have attached debugged code image [image] for better under standing.

Comment: You have a misunderstanding about `Date` objects: a `Date` object does not have a format by itself. It's only a timestamp value. There is no such thing as "a `Date` object without any format change". When you print a `Date` object, it's printed in a default format. The object does not know what the format was that you parsed the original string with. If you need to print a `Date` in a specific format, then you'll have to format it using an appropriate `SimpleDateFormat`. The `Date` object itself does not contain information about formatting.

Comment: @Jesper thanks for clearing the ambiguity.
I would rather like to rephrase my issue.
How can I get above UTC dateTime String as UTC formatted date Object(not a string)!
can you provide me an example for clarification?

Comment: There is **no such thing** as an "UTC formatted `Date` object". A `Date` object does not have a format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a UTC formatted DateTime String

No, you don’t.

UTC is the prime meridian commonly used for time-keeping. Time zones towards the east use an offset some number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of UTC; those to the west, behind UTC.

[UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) has nothing to do with text formats.

> need this String to be converted to DATE Object without any Format change.

There are two `Date` classes in Java. You should specify which you intended.

And, both classes are *terrible*, flawed by poor design decisions. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

> I have a limitation of using SimpleDateFormat as I have to support API<21 also.

Nope, no such limitation. The latest tooling brings most of the *java.time* functionality to earlier Android, via “API de-sugaring”.

To parse, use `DateTimeFormatter` to define a matching formatting pattern. Try the following, but I’ve not yet tested.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-d HH:mm:ss OOOO" ).withLocale( Locale.US ) ; 
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Tip: Educate the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for formatting textual representations of date-time values.

---

All of this has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Please search before posting here.

Comment: sir! thanks for that such a detailed answer, have cleared much of my misconceptions especially the 'API de-sugaring" concept was an awesome thing you taught.
I'm very grateful.